# Adding a cell to another TableView. (selecting an item from a tableview, showing it in another tableview)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, uitableview

I'm building an app which which has built in with 2 different tabs. First tab is is "**Home**" which basically has a tableview with cells that configured from an api.(The api gets me country names for now)
Those cells also have a "Star" button which prints the data of the specific cell for now.

Second tab is **"Saved"** tab(**SavedViewController**), where I want to show the *"starred"* countries, using a tableview.

You can see the image below in order to get an idea for the app.

[App simulation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCS02.png)

The star button has a function in my **CountriesTableViewCell**. I'm using a *saveButtonDelegate* in order to let the **SavedViewController** know about an item is going to be saved. The code in **CountriesTableViewCell** for star button is as below.

```
@objc func buttonTapped() {
    //If Button is selected fill the image. Else unfill it.
    
    if !isSaveButtonSelected {
        saveButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
        isSaveButtonSelected = true
        
        saveButtonDelegate?.saveButtonClicked(with: countryData) //Checking if save button is clicked
    }
}
```

*countryData* is the data that I get from the api, and this is the data I want to pass to **SavedViewController**.

```
struct CountryData: Codable {
let name : String
}
```

So on the **SavedViewController**, I'm handling the data using the *SaveButtonProtocol* conformance as below:

```
extension SavedViewController: SaveButtonProtocol {

func saveButtonClicked(with data: CountryData) {
    countryDataArray.append(data)
    print("saveButtonClicked")
    print("countryData in savevc is \(countryDataArray)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.countriesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Whenever I click the star button on the first tab, this function is getting called on **SavedViewController**. So whenever I click to button, those *print* statements above work fine.

The problem is, whenever the star button is clicked, it should append the data of the current clicked cell to **countryDataArray** in **SavedViewController**. But the array is not populating as it should.

Let's say I pressed the first cell's star button, my *print("countryData in savevc is (countryDataArray)")* statement prints : *["Vatican City"]*, then I press the second cell's star button it only prints *["Ethiopia"]* while it should print **["Vatican City", "Ethiopia"]**

Why this issue is happening? My best guess is I'm delegating *SavedViewController* from the cell class so it behaves differently for every other cell. If that is the problem what should I do to solve it?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Check if you reset countryDataArray somewhere.  Check also that the delegate and savedviewcontroller are always the same. You also should store your data in a shared (static array) object so you only have one source and add the saved indicator in your country struct so you do not rely on what is displayed in one view controller.

Comment: Incredible solution. Static array works really well. Appreciate it much! Learned a new whole concept thanks to you. I can accept your answer if you post it. Thanks

Comment: What is important is to define your model and from where you will access it. If more than one place static properties are useful as there is only one copy shared by all view controller. You can see this in the core data template : only one database instance shared.

Comment: Incredible concept and really well-done explanation. Thanks for broadening my vision! Will definitely use static much more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your data in a shared (static array) object so you only have one source and add the saved indicator in your country struct so you do not rely on what is displayed in one view controller.